# Archlinux iso with linux-5.9 kernel

Tags: linux, arch-linux, iso-image, initramfs-tools

I have built the linux-5.9 kernel using [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel/Traditional_compilation#Manual_method), for the initramfs i have followed the **Automated preset metod** section.

For the iso I followed [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/archiso#Kernel), used the **releng** custom profile (renamed  `custom-profile/` ), added both `vmlinux-linux59` and  `initramfs-linux59.img`  into the `custom-profile/airootfs/boot/` directory. Finally, I created an entry into  `custom-profile/efiboot/loader/entries`:

```
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later

title   Arch Linux CUSTOM install medium (x86_64, UEFI)
linux   /%INSTALL_DIR%/boot/x86_64/vmlinuz-linux59
initrd  /%INSTALL_DIR%/boot/intel-ucode.img
#initrd  /%INSTALL_DIR%/boot/amd-ucode.img
initrd  /%INSTALL_DIR%/boot/x86_64/initramfs-linux59.img
options root="LABEL=%ARCHISO_LABEL%" rw archisobasedir=%INSTALL_DIR% archisolabel=%ARCHISO_LABEL%
```

The iso works fine if in the systemd-boot menu the original kernel is selected, but if the linux59's entry is selected then:

```
:: running early hook [udev]
Starting version 246.6-1-arch
:: running hook [udev]
:: Triggering uevents...
Waiting 10 seconds for device /dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_202010 ...
ERROR: device 'LABEL ARCH_202010' not found. Skipping fsck.
:: mounting 'LABEL=ARCH_202010' on real root 
mount:  /new_root: can't find LABEL=ARCH_202010.
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
sh: can't access tty: job control turned off 
[rootfs ]#
```

I think the problem is the initramfs that i generated with `# mkinitcpio -p linux59`, but i cannot figure out precisely where.

Comment: I think you're more likely to get an answer to this over on SE Unix and Linux.